# Python, Lists - Use 'Item' as integer variable

Tags: python, list

Sorry for the poor title, basically I want to access a `list` item based on another `list` item:

```
catList = [john, james, jack]
dateList = [1y, 2y, 3m]

for item in catList:
    if item in typeList[1]:
        calendar += 1
    if item in typeList[2]:
        connector += 1
        print dateList[item]
```

It's the last line that I want to achieve, essentially to print the value of `dateList` which corresponds to the value of `catList`.

Any ideas? Thanks

Edit: My `catDict` & `dateDict` are `list`s so they don't have keys, just values.

Comment: and what is wrong with the last line?

Comment: What are the values of `catDict`?  Provide specific values of list list.  Also, fix your variable names.  If `catDict` is a list, that's a terrible name.

Comment: are you looking for [zip()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip)?

Comment: Correspond _how_? Do you mean "is at the same position in the list"? So `james` corresponds with `2y`? (I assume you actually mean `'james'` and `'2y'`) If that's what you mean, g.d.d.c's answer is right. If you mean "correspond" in some more complex way, please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keys to catDict are numeric strings you can use `print dateDict[int(item)]`.  Otherwise, I'm uncertain - we need to see what the declaration of catDict looks like.

If you're using lists you want to do this:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(catList):
  print dateList[idx]
```

Comment: See my last edit, I mislead you, I'm using lists, not dictionaries. Sorry!